# React Select - Options with same name

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have options that have been passed with the same "value" . I.e

```
[
  { value: "abc", label: "abc" , id : 0 },
  { value: "abc", label: "abc" , id : 1 },
  { value: "abc", label: "abc" : id : 2 }
];
```

The problem here is since the values are the same, when one option "abc" is selected, all the options in dropdown menu are removed . To over come this, i have implemented :

`isOptionSelected={(option, selectValue) => selectValue.some((i) => i === option); }`

When overriding the default selected behaviour, the dropdown does not consider to the items already been selected (all the items are shown in the drop down).

How would I implement react-select to comply with both usecases ?

```
<Select
        {...props}
        controlShouldRenderValue={!isMulti}
        isMulti={true}
        styles={{
          menu: (provided) => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 }),
        }}
        hideSelectedOption={true}
        isOptionSelected={(option, selectValue) =>
          optionSelected(option, selectValue)
        }
      />
```

Screenshot below for better understanding :

[image]

Comment: Why on earth would you want those duplicates in the UI?  There is absolutely nothing distinguishing them from a UX perspective and they end up just being noise.  This is bad data design.  I say fix the datasource or account for that in the UI by filtering out duplicates.

Comment: The names are totally up to user, its a use case that I will have to deal with.

Comment: What is the use case where those duplicates can exist and what makes it a legitimate use case?  I still say the system should disallow those. "Sorry, that tag already exists"

Comment: Regardless of the use case, if you absolutely must continue in this direction you'll need to pass the Select a list of unique options between value and label.  Do something like append id onto the end of value or something and then parse it back out when the item is selected.